# How to click HTML text with VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web, web-scraping

I'm writing a code to automatically fill some website with cells values:

```
Sub prueba()
Dim oIE As InternetExplorer: Set oIE = New InternetExplorer
Dim oDocument As HTMLDocument
Dim ECICOR As HTMLSelectElement
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim x As Long

oIE.Visible = True

oIE.Navigate "http://sirem.eci.geci/smcfs/console/login.jsp"


Do While oIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop


With oDocument
Set oDocument = oIE.Document
End With
 
 
Call oDocument.parentWindow.execScript("window.parent.sc.postDummyFormForWindow('/smcfs/console/inventory.search');", "JScript")


Set ECICOR = oDocument.getElementById("enterpriseFieldObj")
ECICOR.Focus
ECICOR.Click
ECICOR.Value = "ECICOR"
ECICOR.FireEvent ("onChange")



oDocument.getElementsByClassName("unprotectedinput")(0).Value = Cells(i, 1)
oDocument.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
oDocument.getElementsbyClassName("evenrow")(1).click

End Sub
```

So my problem is that my program doesn't do anything after the last line on the code and I don't know what problem it is because it worked before.

Here you can see the HTML code:

```
<
<TR class=evenrow><TD class=checkboxcolumn><INPUT type=checkbox value=%3CInventoryItem+ItemID%3D%22000000000152030052%22+OrganizationCode%3D%22ECICOR%22+ProductClass%3D%22%22+UnitOfMeasure%3D%22%22%2F%3E name=EntityKey oldChecked="false"> <INPUT type=hidden value=000000000152030052 name=ItemID_1> <INPUT type=hidden name=UOM_1> <INPUT type=hidden name=PC_1> <INPUT type=hidden value=ECICOR name=OrgCode_1> </TD>
<TD class=tablecolumn><A onclick="javascript:showDetailFor('%3CInventoryItem+ItemID%3D%22000000000152030052%22+OrganizationCode%3D%22ECICOR%22+ProductClass%3D%22%22+UnitOfMeasure%3D%22%22%2F%3E');return false;" href="">000000000152030052</A> </TD>
<TD class=tablecolumn></TD>
<TD class=tablecolumn></TD>
<TD class=tablecolumn>001097578527174</TD></TR>">
```

How can I find a solution?

Comment: "code always runs an error" - why aren't you telling us what the error is?

Comment: it's error 438. The value in cells(1,1) is a string.

Comment: ...and what is "Error 438" meant to mean? Is that a HTTP error code? A VBA Runtime error code? It could even be an interpretation of a BSOD stop code... When people ask you for error details you should repeat the _entire message verbatim_ from your computer, not truncate or abbreviate it.

Comment: Error 438 means "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method
Sorry

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` will return an array, not an `Element`. If you have only one element with the `unprotectedinput` class, then you need to get the first element in the array returned by `document.getElementsByClassName()`.